# Proof of singular vectors being the best-fit approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, orthogonality

I am reading the proof of singular vectors being the best-fit approximation. That is:

Let $A \in \mathbb{K}^{IxJ}$ and $v_1, v_2, ..., v_r$ be the singular vectors. For $1 \leq k \leq r$, let $V_k$ be the subspace spanned by $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k$. Then for each $k$, $V_k$ is the best-fit k-dimensional subspace for $A$ i.e.

$V_k = \arg \min_{dim(V) \leq k} \sum_{i \in I} ||A^{(i)} - P_V(A^{(i)})||_2^2 = \arg \max_{dim(V) \leq k} \sum_{i \in I} ||P_V(A^{(i)})||_2^2$

The statement is obviously true for $k = 1$, and I understand that.

The proof states that for $k = 2$, let $W$ be a best-fit 2-dimensional subspace for A. Now choose a basis $w_1, w_2$ of $W$ so that $w_2$ is orthogonal to $v_1$. If $v_1$ were orthogonal to W, any unit vector in $W$ will do as $w_2$. If not, choose $w_2$ to be the unit vector in $W$ perpendicular to the projection of $v_1$ onto $W$. Since $v_1$ was chosen to maximize $||Av_1||_2^2$, it follows that $||Aw_1||_2^2 \leq ||Av_1||_2^2$. Since $v_2$ was chosen to maximize $||Av_2||$ over all $v$ orthogonal to $v_1$ one has also $||Aw_2||_2^2 \leq ||Av_2||_2^2$. Thus:

$$||Aw_1||_2^2 + ||Aw_2||_2^2 \leq ||Av_1||_2^2 + ||Av_2||_2^2 $$

I am confused about two things:

1. We have a 2-dimensional linear subspace W. Let's call $w'_1, w'_2$ an orthonormal basis such that $span (w'_1,w'_2) = W$. As far as I understood the proof suggests to represent the same space $W$ with $w_1,w_2$ and to take $w_2$ to be either perpendicular to $v_1$ or perpendicular to the orthogonal projection of $v_1$ onto $W$. My question is when we have this restriction how can we be so sure that we will be able to find $w_1,w_2$ such that $span(w_1,w_2) = span (w'_1, w'_2) = W$?
2. Let's assume we cannot find a $w_2$ such that $w_2$ is perpendicular to $v_1$ so we pick $w_2$ to be perpendicular to the orthogonal projection of $v_1$ onto $W$. In that case how can we ensure that  $||Aw_2||_2^2 \leq ||Av_2||_2^2$?

Comment: The orthogonal projection of $v_1$ onto $W$ will be a vector in $W$. Rescale so it has norm one, and call that $w_1$. Since $W$ is a two-dimensional space, you can find another $w_2$ that is perpendicular. That is guaranteed by Gram-Schmidt: you pick any other linearly independent vector and subtract an appropriate amount of $w_1$ from it so that it is perpendicular, and then rescale it to have size such that $||Aw_2||_2^2 \leq ||Av_2||_2^2$ holds, and call that $w_2$.

Comment: I understand your statement about Gram-Schmidt but I am lost on the second one. Because we are not trying to find a $w_2$ such that $||Aw_2||_2^2 \leq ||Av_2||_2^2$, we want to make sure that for any $w_2$ this will hold. edit: Actually on Gram-Schmidt, I know we can find a vector $w_2$ such that dim(W) =2. But how can we ensure that span($w_1,w_2) = W$, since W is a subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$?